# Persisting File to App Engine Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

The App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) for the Blobstore gives a pretty thorough explanation of how to upload a file using the `BlobstoreUploadHandler` provided by the `webapp` framework.

However, I have a `cgi.FieldStorage` instance that I would like to store directly into the Blobstore. In other words, I don't need to upload the file since this is taken care of by other means; I just need to store it.

I've been looking through the `blobstore` module [source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/#appengine%2Fapi%2Fblobstore) to try to understand how the upload handler creates/generates blobstore keys and ultimately writes files to the blobstore itself, but I'm getting lost. It seems like the `CreateUploadURLResponse` in `blobstore_service_pb` is where the actual write would occur, but I'm not seeing the component that actually implements that functionality.

**Update**

There is also an implementation for storing files directly into the filesystem, which I think is what the upload handler does in the end. I am not entirely sure about this, so an explanation as to whether or not using the `FileBlobStorage` is the correct way to go would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the [deprecation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api) of the files API you can no longer write directly to blobstore.
You should write to Google Cloud Storage instead. For that you can use the [AE GCS client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)
Files written to Google Cloud Storage could be served by the Blobstore API by [creating a blob key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.create_gs_key).

Comment: Something is writing to the blobstore when we use the `BlobstoreUploadHandler` though, right? If that's the case, can't we use the same process to store a blob ourselves? I'm not saying that I won't switch to GCS, but I am interested in what I could do if I would've had to stick with the blobstore

Comment: I would recommend you to forget about blobstore and use only GCS unless you have a lot of code which uses on blobstore.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi not too much code dependent on blobstore. GCS it is

Comment: Yes, going with GCS is the preferred way but just to answer your question regarding how `BlobstoreUploadHandler` does it. When you are providing a url for upload the upload is done directly to blobstore and the handler just gets a reference to the already uploaded files.